# How to compute the total speed

Tags: cpu-speed, cpu-cores

I am hiring a VPS (Perfetto4) from Mochahost with 2 cores of 2,27GHz. The promissed speed is 2,7GHz total. The multiplier is 11. How do I calculate the total speed of CPU? Is 2 cores of 2,27GHz compatible with total speed of 2,7GHz?

Comment: GHz are 10^9 Hz, a frequency as the number of beats of your heart. In common speach we say our heart _runs_. The comparison in perforfmance between 2 computer is usually made via benchmarks that put under _pressure_ the whole system, cpu, memory, bus... maybe you are interested in mega flops per second unit... if I've to guess it's an error 2.27 to 2.7...

Comment: In the context of VPS, the GHz figures are not actual CPU core GHz but with what the hypervizor measures CPU capacity that is given to the VPS. It should be consistent within the virtualisation system, but not necessarily with a real hardware of the same specs. The actual total vCPU performance that is delivered to you VPS depends on the overall load of the host machine, if and how much the provider is over-booking the host CPU capacity, and if your guest has some prioritised/reserved CPU capacity allocated to it.

Comment: I would agree with Hastur that its likely "up to 2.7Ghz". If your VPS has 2.27GHZ CPU unless these CPUs boost their frequency to 2.7GHz there isn't a way for them to run at 2.7Ghz. does not matter if its physical or virtual really.  There is still physical hardware.